# Does the bonferonni correction change the outcome of the p-value or is it just changin what you accept as significant?

Tags: r, t-test, multiple-comparisons, bonferroni

For some reason I can't seem to integrate the bonferonni corrected p adjustment into my multiple comparisons t test in r so I need to do each of my 3 tests individually.
What I wondered was do I need to change something about the t tests or do I just look at the p values they produce and see if they're greater or less than my bonferonni corrected p value (0.016) after having done a normal t test.

Comment: Answering the title question: it is the latter. The correction changes the chosen significance level (0.016 instead of 0.050), not the test statistic with its associated p-value.

Answer (score 2):

You can look at it from either angle.

I would tend to agree with @RichardHardy that it is easier to understand in terms of the latter: reject a null $H_i$ if the corresponding $p$-value $p_i$ is less than $\alpha/n$, where $\alpha$ is the desired level and $n$ the number of tests performed: reject if $p_i\leq \alpha/n$.

But you can also calculate "adjusted" $p$-values - so do something which might fall under the header of "changing" the test statistic - that allow to you continue to use the default cutoff $\alpha$. In the Bonferroni case, all you need to do is to multiply the $p_i$ by $n$ and reject if the adjusted $p$-values are less than $\alpha$: reject if $n\cdot p_i\leq \alpha$.

This is also what `p.adjust` in `R` does:

```
> p.adjust(c(.01,0.04), method = "bonferroni")
[1] 0.02 0.08
```